# Casting String Drag and Drop Object

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

My MouseMove Method

```
 var de = DragDropEffects.Copy;
 var df = DataFormats.Text;

 string[] dragObject = new string[] {
 "#Name#",
   _dragStartHitInfo.Node.GetValue("TextDisplay").ToString()
  };

 data.SetData(df, dragObject);

 treeList.DoDragDrop(data, de);
```

and in my dragdrop method

```
 var data = e.Data.GetData("System.String[]", true) as string[];
string strFieldName = Regex.Replace(data[1], "[^0-9A-Za-z]+", "");
  if (data == null)
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
                return;
            }
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

            if (data[0] != "#Name#") return;
```

However, I am getting a null value for data. Everytime I drop the object, how can I properly set Object type

Comment: Completely off-topic : why are you using `de` and `df` variables ? if you are using their values only once I suggest that you use the value instead (`data.SetData( DataFormats.Text,dragObject);`) otherwise use a better variable name such as `textDataFormat` and `copyEffect`

Comment: This is for my tester, since I want to manipulate the variables without taking to much of my time changing it everytime I Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the text that is being dropped, then use

```
var data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be handled using

```
var baseObj = (System.Windows.Forms.DataObject)e.Data; 
string sFormat = baseObj.GetFormats();
var data = baseObj.GetData("System.String");

var getInnerData = data as System.String[];
```